# How to set subdomain with s3 and cloudflare?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, dns

I want to assign http://remo.babylook.mom/ on s3 bucket http://babylook-remo.s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com.

I set Cloudflare like this tho,

[image]

I got this error.

```
Code: NoSuchBucket
Message: The specified bucket does not exist
BucketName: remo.babylook.mom
RequestId: 8F85DEC6EA4AB692
HostId: T7Mikx7Fj7fBMJhSbSVDjelX0BGkK87QY40BnTdH0Ga2wqt6c8C/s+LTChQ90uehEV3KmtkxMU4=
```

Do you know how to set this? I can see s3 website normally with s3 address. And also, I'm using http://babylook.mom/ and working well.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to add the following record:

```
Name: http://remo.babylook.mom/
Value/Target: http://babylook-remo.s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/
Type: CNAME
```

Comment: Thanks bro. I added the question information just now tho, I have already added domain information like your advice. But it doesn't work.